# CiviCRM Error - type E_ERROR was caused in line 550

Tags: wordpress

I've got a wordpress site using CiviCRM and recently got an alert email indicating a technical issue identified on the site. Error details is listed below. I've googled for similar issues but went nowhere. Wondering if anyone has come across this or similar ? Any advice will be much appreciated.

## Error Details

```
An error of type E_ERROR was caused in line 550 of the file /public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/symfony/filesystem/Filesystem.php. 
Error message: Uncaught Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Exception\IOException: A temporary file could not be created. in /public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/symfony/filesystem/Filesystem.php:550
Stack trace:
#0 /public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/symfony/filesystem/Filesystem.php(598): Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Filesystem->tempnam('/home/...', 'CachedCiviConta...')
#1 /public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/symfony/config/ResourceCheckerConfigCache.php(138): Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Filesystem->dumpFile('/home/...', '
```

Answer (score 1):

This error is telling you that due to a filesystem (IO) error the system could not save a temporary file.

This could be due to:

- Hardware issues with the storage medium.
- No free disk space available.
- Incorrect/insufficient permissions to save files in the location required.

You should check that the webserver/PHP user has permission to write to the location which will be in the full logs in your installation's [ConfigAndLog](https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/troubleshooting/#review-the-civicrm-log) folder in the [CiviCRM files directory](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/framework/filesystem/).